# Dropbox OAuth callback to Mule using https

Tags: oauth, mule, dropbox-api

Dropbox requires the callback URL to be over HTTPS (when not using localhost).

Using Mule 3.6.0 with the latest dropbox connector, the callback defaults to http - thus only working with localhost.  For production I need to use https for the OAuth dance.

What is the correct way to specify a https callback URL?

I've tried:

```
  <https:connector name="connector.http.mule.default">
    <https:tls-key-store path="${ssl.certfile}" keyPassword="${ssl.keyPass}" storePassword="${ssl.storePass}"/>
  </https:connector>

  <dropbox:config name="Dropbox" appKey="${dropbox.appKey}" appSecret="${dropbox.appSecret}" doc:name="Dropbox">
    <dropbox:oauth-callback-config domain="production.mydomain.com"  path="callback" />
  </dropbox:config>
```

But it errors:

```
Endpoint scheme must be compatible with the connector scheme. Connector is: "https", endpoint is "http://production.mydomain.com:8052/callback"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with that solved the problem:

```
<https:connector name="connector.http.mule.default"  doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
  <https:tls-key-store path="${ssl.certfile}" keyPassword="${ssl.keyPass}" storePassword="${ssl.storePass}"/>
</https:connector>

<dropbox:config name="Dropbox" appKey="${dropbox.appKey}" appSecret="${dropbox.appSecret}" doc:name="Dropbox">
  <dropbox:oauth-callback-config domain="myserver.domain.com"  path="callback" connector-ref="connector.http.mule.default" localPort="8052" remotePort="8052"/>
</dropbox:config>
```

This works great for localhost, but not if you need the callback to go to something other than localhost (e.g. myserver.domain.com)

Reviewing mule.log you can see that the connector binds to localhost (127.0.0.0) despite the config pointing to:

```
domain="myserver.domain.com"
```

Log Entry:

```
INFO  ... Attempting to register service with name: Mule.Ops:type=Endpoint,service="DynamicFlow-https://localhost:8052/callback",connector=connector.http.mule.default,name="endpoint.https.localhost.8052.callback"
INFO  ... Registered Endpoint Service with name: Mule.Ops:type=Endpoint,service="DynamicFlow-https://localhost:8052/callback",connector=connector.http.mule.default,name="endpoint.https.localhost.8052.callback"
INFO  ... Registered Connector Service with name Mule.Ops:type=Connector,name="connector.http.mule.default.1"
```

The workaround is to force Mule to listen to 0.0.0.0 for connectors which define localhost as the endpoint.

In wrapper.conf set

```
wrapper.java.additional.x=-Dmule.tcp.bindlocalhosttoalllocalinterfaces=TRUE
```